# Will voiding an envelope through API always trigger an email to the customer

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign rest api to manage envelopes sent to clients and voiding envelopes. My question is that if I put in a PUT request to void an envelope, will this always trigger an email sent to the customer that their envelope is voided.

I have a function that handles docusign callback, where we handle the response, and then we send an email to the customer that their envelope has been voided, but we're not sure if Docusign is also doing that as well

Is there any way to confirm that Docusign is always sending an email to customer when we void an envelope through the API. Just concerned what I have might potentially send two emails to the customer about the same thing

Any help would be great

Cheers,

Comment: is recipient has a DocuSign account or an accountless signer? If recipient has a DocuSign account then they can switch off the void notification in their My Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

When a DocuSign envelope is voided, DocuSign will send a *void notification* email to any (remote) recipient that has previously received any other email from DocuSign for that envelope (for example, a *signing invitation* email for a signer recipient or a *carbon copy* email for a cc recipient).

For example, let's say you create/send an envelope with 2 (remote) recipients, and specify routing order 1 for the first recipient and routing order 2 for the second recipient.

- When you create/send the envelope, the first recipient (routing order = 1) will receive a signing invitation email from DocuSign. If you void the envelope prior to that first signer completing the envelope (i.e., prior to the second recipient receiving the signing invitation email), the void notification email would only be sent to the first recipient (because only they've been previously emailed about that envelope).
- However, if the first recipient completes the envelope before you void it, the second recipient will be sent their signing invitation email -- so if you were to void the envelope at that time, both recipient 1 and recipient 2 would receive the void notification email.

You should be able to confirm this behavior by testing this scenario using the DocuSign demo environment (i.e., developer sandbox).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this issue. The issue I'm currently having at the moment is that when I'm testing locally and I void an envelope through REST API, it sends the void notification email to the actual users email 

When I do the same action on a stage environment it doesn't send an email directly to the user, but looks like its sending to the developer account. So I'm not sure what particular action is happening on production

Is there a way to see a list of all system generated void notification emails sent by Docusign from an account?